# Can I migrate from 19.10 to 20.10 Without re-installing?

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10, 20.10, migration

I already reinstall, but i ask.My updates are not working. Now, i am backuping.

Comment: Is [this reference](https://sourcedigit.com/26267-upgrade-ubuntu-19-10-to-20-10/) helpful?

Comment: First of all 19.10 is EOL ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)), then no, skipping over releases is not supported. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)